# How to Dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

As a new user to linux, I thought I would start off with the latest version of Ubuntu (14.10) since it is the only one I'm familiar with. After trying numerous times, changing UEFI settings and watching numerous how to videos, I'm still unable to successfully boot Ubuntu from my usb stick. Here are the specs for my laptop in case it should help...

Make: Toshiba /
Model: Satellite C50D-B-120 (No optical Disk Drive) /
CPU: AMD E1-6010 /
OS: Windows 8.1 64bit

I've tried turning off secure boot, fast boot, changing usb priority, and every time I feel as though I'm almost there, I have a message pop up after restarting the system saying, reboot system or insert media over and over again. I don't know what's wrong and I can't find the answers I'm looking for, so I hope the Ubuntu community can help solve my dilemma a soon so I can begin my new experience.

Comment: I just realized a mistake in my title; it's supposed to be how to dual boot Ubuntu 14.10 with Windows 8.1. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did it the only change I made was to disable fast boot. I left secure boot and everything else in BIOS alone.

In Windows go to **Control Panel** and **Administrative Tools**, then select *Disk Manager*. Select your partition and shrink to size you would like your Ubuntu to be. When it finishes, it will show as unallocated space, leave it like this.

Now restart the installation process. You should now get an option to install alongside Windows boot manager. Go through the install process. When done restart.

For me, because I left secure boot and BIOS alone, after install and restart it will just boot Windows with no option to boot Ubuntu. On my hp laptop, I have to do the following to get to GRUB to select Ubuntu:

After I turn on I have to press <kbd>f9</kbd> right away, select Ubuntu, and then GRUB launches. From there I select Ubuntu again and press <kbd>enter</kbd> and it boots.

Edit: I think I misread. If you can't even get the USB to boot up, the Ubuntu iso may not have setup correctly. In Windows download Linux live USB creator and use that to make your USB your Ubuntu installation media and bootable. The above instructions still apply.

Edit 2: okay, it might be a good idea to download iso again. Once downloaded use Linux live USB creator to create bootable USB. Restart and then go to BIOS, restore default (f10) usually and save.

If you have a recovery partition and the option to back it up, I suggest you do that. My hp laptop allowed me to create one backup of my recovery. That way, if something goes wrong and you ever lose Windows you can get it back.

If you have the option to back up, do that first and then try to install Ubuntu again. Just when you install make sure you get the option "install alongside Windows 8" or "install alongside windows boot manager".

If you don't get one of those two options and continue with the install you will lose Windows

Comment: I've just tried the method you suggested, although whether it was correct or not I still wasn't able to get it running. Sorry if I initially caused any confusion and thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: What is your primary OS, Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: My primary is windows. And going back to the usb scenario, I originally used pendrive linux. Is there any advantage to the Linux Live usb creator you suggested?

Comment: I'm going to add something to answer so if it helps you can mark it as complete. In regards to Linux live USB creator I have NEVER had an issue with booting/installing via USB. Other things like netbootin gave me problems.

Comment: Ok I'm trying it now.

Comment: If you have option to back up your Windows recovery, I would do that first, then install... Just in case you missed my last edit

Comment: Hopefully in the end the install will be successful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Follow my instructions and you should be good. This is exactly how I did it on my hp with 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install Ubuntu on uefi system from my experience is this:

disable fast boot,
enble sata achi,
enable usb boot,
disable secure boot.

After that download and use RUFUS to make bootable USB, with gpt uefi partitioning, fat formatted.

P.S. My uefi on Lenovo Y580 have some bug, so to detect bootable USB I have to enter uefi at least twice to configure boot order. First time uefi just do not see usb.